# Expected Expression Error when Using UIPopoverViewController

Tags: ios, expression

this is my first post here.  I'll try to get to the point quickly, as I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem yet.  I'm just starting out.

I'm trying to load a view as a popover, and I'm following some tutorials online, but I'm getting an error when I go to compile.  Here's the offending code:

```
-(IBAction)contestButton:(id)sender;
{
contestView *screen = [[contestView alloc] init];
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contestView];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(615, 650)];
[screen release];
}
```

And the error:

"Expected expression before 'contestView' "

I apologize for what seems to me like a very small mistake that I just can't seem to snake out, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a class named `contestView`.  You have created an instance of `contestView` and stored it in the variable `screen`.  Then you try to pass `contestView` (the class name) as an argument to the selector `initWithContentViewController:`.  You cannot pass a bare class name as an argument.

Perhaps you meant to say this:

```
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
    initWithContentViewController:screen];
```

By the way, it is conventional in iOS programming to start a class name with a capital letter.  So you should strongly consider renaming the class to `ContestView`.

Also, the method `-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:]` takes an instance of `UIViewController` as an argument - not an instance of `UIView`.  If your `contestView` class is a subclass of `UIView`, you will get a different error once you fix your call to say `screen` instead of `contestView`.

If `contestView` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, you should rename it to `ContestViewController`.